# How to use all the cpu cores using Dask?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have a pandas series with more than 35000 rows. I want to use dask make it more efficient. However, I both the dask code and the pandas code are taking the same time.
Initially *"ser"* is pandas series and *fun1* and *fun2* are basic functions performing pattern match in individual rows of series.

Pandas:

```
ser = ser.apply(fun1).apply(fun2)
```

Dask:

```
ser = dd.from_pandas(ser, npartitions = 16)
ser = ser.apply(fun1).apply(fun2)
```

On checking the status of cores of cpu, I found that not all the cores were getting used. Only one core was getting used to 100%.

Is there any method to make the series code faster using dask or utilize all the cores of cpu while performing Dask operations in series?

Answer (score 29):

See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html

It is likely that the functions that you are calling are pure-python, and so claim the GIL, the lock which ensures that only one python instruction is being carried out at a time within a thread. In this case, you will need to run your functions in separate processes to see any parallelism. You could do this by using the multiprocess scheduler

```
ser = ser.apply(fun1).apply(fun2).compute(scheduler='processes')
```

or by using the distributed scheduler (which works fine on a single machine, and actually comes with some next-generation benefits, such as the status dashboard); in the simplest, default case, creating a client is enough:

```
client = dask.distributed.Client()
```

but you should read [the docs](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Still only uses 1 or 2 cores out of 8. Strange.

Comment: You should tweak the number of worker processes and threads-per-process in the call to Client. You want 1 thread per worker.

Comment: at least for me, distributed seems extremely buggy, by default the latest version `'2023.12.1'` throws a "list is not hashable by just instantiating the Client", just a heads up...